# Transform one object w/ the matrix4() of another (THREE.js r84)

Tags: html, three.js

I wish to move a cube based on the movement of another cube to which TransformControls is attached by means of Matrix4() method only.

The attempts so far have failed to shift the follower cube.
I'm not sure why the follower doesn't seem to take the world co-ordinates of the directing cube.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <title>three.js webgl - transform controls</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
      <style>
       body {
        margin: 0px;
        background-color: #000000;
        color: #fff;
        font-family:Monospace;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 30px;
        overflow: hidden;
       }
       #info {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px; width: 100%;
        padding: 15px;
        z-index:100;
       }
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
    
      <div id="info">
      "W" translate | "E" rotate | "R" scale | "+" increase size | "-" decrease size<br />
      Press "Q" to toggle world/local space, keep "Ctrl" down to snap to grid
      </div>
    
      <script src="build/three.js"></script>
      <script src="js/controls/TransformControls.js"></script>
      <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    
      <script>
       var camera, scene, renderer, control, mesh, mesh1;
       init();
       animate();
       //render();
       //update();
       function init() {
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        renderer.sortObjects = false;
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        //
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 3000 );
        camera.position.set( 1000, 500, 1000 );
        camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 200, 0 ) );
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.add( new THREE.GridHelper( 1000, 10 ) );
        var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 2 );
        light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
        scene.add( light );
        //var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'textures/crate.gif', render );
        //texture.mapping = THREE.UVMapping;
        //texture.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true } );
        control = new THREE.TransformControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        control.addEventListener( 'change', render );
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( mesh );
        control.attach( mesh );
        scene.add( control );
        
        var followerCube = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
        var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff9909 } );
        mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( followerCube, mesh1 );
    
        scene.updateMatrixWorld();
        mesh1.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
        
        var relativeMeshOffset = new THREE.Vector3( 100, 100, 200 );
        
        var offsetPosition = relativeMeshOffset.applyMatrix4( mesh.matrixWorld );
        
        mesh1.position.x = offsetPosition.x;
        mesh1.position.y = offsetPosition.y;
        mesh1.position.z = offsetPosition.z;
        
        scene.add( mesh1 );
        console.log(mesh1.position);
        
        var orbitControl = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        orbitControl.addEventListener( 'change', render );
        
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        window.addEventListener( 'keydown', function ( event ) {
         switch ( event.keyCode ) {
          case 81: // Q
           control.setSpace( control.space === "local" ? "world" : "local" );
           break;
          case 17: // Ctrl
           control.setTranslationSnap( 100 );
           control.setRotationSnap( THREE.Math.degToRad( 15 ) );
           break;
          case 87: // W
           control.setMode( "translate" );
           break;
          case 69: // E
           control.setMode( "rotate" );
           break;
          case 82: // R
           control.setMode( "scale" );
           break;
          case 187:
          case 107: // +, =, num+
           control.setSize( control.size + 0.1 );
           break;
          case 189:
          case 109: // -, _, num-
           control.setSize( Math.max( control.size - 0.1, 0.1 ) );
           break;
         }
        });
        window.addEventListener( 'keyup', function ( event ) {
         switch ( event.keyCode ) {
          case 17: // Ctrl
           control.setTranslationSnap( null );
           control.setRotationSnap( null );
           break;
         }
        });
       }
       function onWindowResize() {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        render();
       }
       
       function animate() {
       
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        render();
        update();
       
       }
       
       function update() {
       
        var relativeMeshOffset = new THREE.Vector3( 100, 100, 200 );
        
        var offsetPosition = relativeMeshOffset.applyMatrix4( mesh.matrixWorld );
        
        mesh1.position.x = offsetPosition.x;
        mesh1.position.y = offsetPosition.y;
        mesh1.position.z = offsetPosition.z;
        
       }
       
       function render() {
        control.update();
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
       }
      </script>
    
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause you set `mesh1.matrixAutoUpdate = false;` in line 75. If you do that, the `mesh1` wouldn't change its position.

Comment: Thanks! It works for regular geometry now, but in one case which would be useful I cannot get a clipping plane to move when following the same code pattern. Is there an extra step such as first updating a different object which in turn updates the clipping plane?

Comment: @MurServ Sorry, I don't know what 'clipping plane' really mean, can you explain more clear? Or, which case you get the question?

Comment: Thank you, I meant that I couldn't get one of these to move according to the position of a box mesh with THREE.transformControls attached. However, I was able to alter this example to do so: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_clipping_advanced     ...Whomsoever is similarly stuck and wishes to get the clipping plane to follow the mesh based on this example should change the "var transform = new THREE.matrix4()" to then "transform.copy(desired object)" and delete the "bouncy" temporal scalar.

Comment: A `Matrix4` can represent how is an object stay in space, like orientation and translation, so, if you get the transform matrix, just apply it to your target mesh, be careful there are two kinds of matrix, one is local matrix, another is world matrix.